# Swiper.js Responsiveness issues

Tags: swiper.js

I want to display 3 slides on large screens and 1.5 on mobile screens, but if I set the slidesPerView to 3, it affects the mobile and it makes it look horrible.

This is how i configured it

```
          <Swiper
            className={styles.swiper}
            slidesPerView={3}
            spaceBetween={0}
            modules={[Navigation, Pagination]}
            navigation
            pagination={{ clickable: true }}
          >
            <SwiperSlide>
              <Product />
            </SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>
              <Product />
            </SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>
              <Product />
            </SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>
              <Product />
            </SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>
              <Product />
            </SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>
              <Product />
            </SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>
              <Product />
            </SwiperSlide>
          </Swiper>
```

and this is what it looks like on Large screens
[image]

and here is what it looks like on mobile which is badddd

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
breakpoints={{
    // when window width is >= 640px
    640: {
      width: 640,
      slidesPerView: 1.5,
    },
    // when window width is >= 768px
    768: {
      width: 768,
      slidesPerView: 3,
    },
  }}`enter code here`
```

Change the breakpoints to something that fits your needs better